# Entity Framework Many-to-Many relationship: Error on insert

Tags: entity-framework, ef-code-first

I have the following two classes that I need to establish a many-to-many relationship between:

```
public class ContentItem
{
  public int ContentItemId {get; set; }
  public virtual ICollection<Category> Categories {get; set; }
  // Other properties...
}

public class Category
{
  public int CategoryId {get; set; }
  public string CategoryName {get; set; }
  // Other properties
}
```

I have the following EntityTypeConfiguration class:

```
public class ContentItemConfiguration : EntityTypeConfiguration<ContentItem>
{
    public ContentItemConfiguration()
    {
        Property(_ => _.ContentItemId)
            .HasDatabaseGeneratedOption(DatabaseGeneratedOption.Identity);

        HasMany(_ => _.InterestCategories)
            .WithMany()
            .Map(_ =>
            {
                _.ToTable("ContentItemCategory", "CMS");
                _.MapLeftKey("ContentItemId");
                _.MapRightKey("CategoryId");
            });
    }
}
```

When I add a migration for the above configuration, the appropriate tables and FKs are created.  I then try to do an insert with the following code:

```
        var itemToAdd = new ContentItem
        {
          // Set various properties here
        };

        itemToAdd.Categories.Add(dbContext.Categories.First());

        dbContext.ContentItems.Add(itemToAdd);
        dbContext.SaveChanges();
```

When I call SaveChanges, I end up with the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: A dependent property in a ReferentialConstraint is mapped to a store-generated column. Column: 'ContentItemId'.

I've checked and the only place I can see that `ContentItemId` should be store generated (identity) is in the Content table.  The join table that EF scaffolds does have a `ContentId` column but it is not set to identity so I'm not sure where I've gone wrong with my mapping.  Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Please post the class and the mapping for the entity with the ContentId Column.

Comment: That was a typo on my part, should have read ContentItemId.  The entity in question is ContentItem.  The class and it's corresponding configuration are included in the question.

Comment: Aren't there any other FKs to `ContentItem`?

Comment: The error cannot be reproduced with the simplified model you posted. I've copied it to a simple test Project assuming InterestCategories is also a typo. With EF 6.1.1 this workes fine. Because of the “Referencial Constrint” error I’m assuming it has something to do with a one to many relation.

Comment: @GertArnold *sigh* thanks for getting me thinking in the right direction.  There was indeed another FK on ContentItem.  I was sure it was the many:many relationship that would be giving me fits so I didn't even consider that it might be the 1:many relationship that was the source of the problem.  Turns out that the many:many was configured just fine but I had botched the 1:many.